# Separate the back and the upvote buttons

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, ios-app

The back button in the top left corner is too close to the upvote arrow for a question/answer on an iPhone for my fingers. I often touch the back button by mistake instead of the upvote arrow.

[image: screenshot]

The upvote/score/downvote arrows group could be moved down to create some space between them and the back button.
For example, in the question, the top row could be occupied by the question title, and the upvote/downvote arrows could be beneath the title on the left, as they are on the main website.

Comment: I don't know that I follow your suggestion of where to put the arrows on a question without losing a lot of usable space. Any way you could mock that up?

Comment: I've updated the screenshot

Comment: I'll take a look at this

Comment: Thanks. Your screenshot is for answers. Looks like @Arie had a similar concern, but found a compromise. +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've moved the voting controls down a bit to solve your issue. However, in order to keep the position of these controls equal on the question and answer side, I did not lower them  too much. Though subtle, this change should make things better.

These changes will take effect in version **0.1.61.**

[image: Answer with an increased space on the top]

Comment: it is only natural that the first attempt to upvote your answer ended up in tapping the back button. :)