# Bigger vote buttons

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

The voting buttons for the iOS app are quite small: I looked around to see if anyone had asked about this yet and all I found is that the tag buttons were made larger at some point in the past.

Is the button size a problem for anyone else? If I don't hit it on the first or second try, I can usually get it on the third, but I feel like it should be easier to hit those ever-important buttons.

Comment: related: [Separate the back and the upvote buttons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230554/separate-the-back-and-the-upvote-buttons)

Comment: FWIW, I had the same reaction, but tend to fall pretty far toward the "oldster" end of our demo, so I thought it might just be me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made their tapping area a bit bigger.

These changes will apply in version **0.1.61**.